# How can we get malicious links removed on a locked question?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, locked-posts

I was searching Google on JavaScript charting libraries, as we are looking to see what else is out there besides Google's visualization library. I came across [this old Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library).

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119996/1195273), starting with **timepedia.org** (I don't want to actually put the full link here) which has two upvotes, provided a link to what was probably a legitimate charting library at some point, but it now redirects to a malicious site.

Upon discovering this, my reaction was to edit the answer and remove the link. I noticed that I don't have this ability as the question has been ***locked***. I looked around for a way to flag attention to the answer as well, but I couldn't find any way to do that.

What course of action should be taken to get links like this removed in locked questions? How can we get malicious links removed from locked questions?

Comment: Aside: I'm guessing this is why recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: One of many, yes. Only mods can edit said questions/answers, so posting here on meta is pretty much the only course of action.

Comment: While you can't edit answers on a locked question, you can still flag it no?

Comment: @Patrice: Nope, not a historically-locked one.

Comment: I don't even know why that post was locked in the first place; it should have just been deleted.

Comment: Flag a post of your own, with custom reason, and include a link to the problem post and the details. If you flag a question, you get a bit more space

Comment: @BoltClock interesting. I would've guessed that no matter how "locked" a post could get, there would always be a way to bring some attention up to it. So short of Bill Woodger's suggestion or using Meta, if there's a mess in a locked question, we can't do much?

Comment: @Servy: Presumably, no one was willing to mirror the content elsewhere.

Comment: @BoltClock That should be a huge sign that the content isn't valuable enough to merit a lock.

Comment: @durron597 Done. Your assumption is correct. The other links appear to be benign.

Comment: What's malicious about the link? It's dead, and there are ads, but I don't see any malware or phishing or or anything attempting to activate on my machine that warrants intervention beyond other dead links.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It seems to take you to different places each time you click it. The first time I hit it, it took me to one of those sites that claims I have a malware installed, and need to install their software to remove it. Sure, not technically *malware*. Also, not something to which SO should be promoting links is it?

Comment: @crush Makes sense, that's sketchy enough for me. I guess I got lucky and they just showed me some generic ads. Removed.

Comment: @Jeremy: can we (somehow) close and delete that question? It's purely asking for a software recommendation, it's (almost) seven years old, software-recommendations have been considered off-topic ([Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)) since at least November, 2010, and while I haven't checked any of the answers' recommendations, given the scale of project death and link-rot, I'd be surprised if half of the answers there are still relevant and/or still exist. Under those circumstances how does that question 'improve the internet'?

Comment: @DavidThomas I found most of the data there severely outdated. I was surprised to find the Q&A in my Google results at all.

Comment: Wow the information in those *"answers"* were atrocious recommendations 5 years ago. Internet time is a few orders of magnitude faster than wall clock time.

Comment: I thinks this question is **historically locked** as a negative proof that recommendation questions are not constructive especially after some time has passed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The right way to handle this situation is to... um... post on Meta. So I suggest you... post on Meta about it, if you... um... haven't already.

Joking aside, you've already done the right thing, don't worry about it any more. Eventually a moderator will see it (shouldn't take very long) and will fix the problem.

Also, I want to agree with [@ryanyuyu's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303547/how-can-we-get-malicious-links-removed-on-a-locked-question#comment238661_303547) that this one of many reasons why recommendation questions are off topic.

Comment: I'd hate to spam meta with posts like this for each individual occurrence. Granted, I don't come across this kind of thing very often, as there probably are only a handful of locked questions. Would it be better to just allow the answers to still be flagged? What are the drawbacks to allowing the flagging of answers on a locked question?

Comment: @crush: We (the mods) will get a bunch of "link-only answer" flags from people who don't understand what a historical lock is about.

Comment: @crush As you've said, there are very few locked questions.  Questions are also only supposed to be locked when they're *very* valuable, so you generally shouldn't expect to see a lot of notable problems with locked questions.

Comment: @BoltClock Am I actually correct? Are you (or another mod) going to remove the link? Or because it's "historical" will it be preserved?

Comment: @durron597: Welllllll I'm not the kind of person who would sneak into a museum to rearrange artifacts at 3 in the morning (where I am right now...).

Comment: @BoltClock I thought unicorns were known for that sort of thing.

Comment: @Servy yeah only [about 2,500](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion) of them... "very few" indeed

Comment: @gnat - 0.025% is pretty rare in my book.

Comment: @gnat Those aren't historically locked posts, those are posts just normally locked.  They can still be flagged, just not edited or voted on.  It also doesn't lock the answers to those questions.

Comment: @durron597: especially the u̶n̶i̶c̶o̶r̶n totally a human whose likeness BoltClock was using for a while there....

Comment: i am the author of that answer, and i would like to amend it to point it to the source repo instead, which is at https://code.google.com/p/gwt-chronoscope/

Comment: @Chii if you want to make sure that request gets noticed by someone other than me, you should write your own answer and/or ping a moderator

Answer (score -6):

- Having a global blacklist would make sense.
- Users can contribute to it, Qualified moderators have to approve entries (avoiding conflicts, whether certain sites are malicious or still acceptable).
- Stackexchange should be scanned regularly. Including closed questions. (So this would cover the OP´s use case).
- a report-link function would be handy (also not disabled for closed questions), extracting the links found in particular Question (,comments ,answers) and offering, which ones to report. Giving a choice, whether the entire domains appears malicious or just a particular [partial] path (without getting to complicated: much like ad-blocking)
- if implemented, doing so and having a global list across all stackexcange sites would make great sense.

Having said all that, is the SO network making any use of google's or Mozilla's knowledge of bad sites?

Development effort, yes, but it may lift manual future efforts by automatic means. Just my 5¢ 8-)