# What is the best way to enter mathematics into the Stack Overflow question body?

Tags: support, markdown, mathjax

I want to be able to enter equations and other mathematics notation into a question body here on Stack Overflow. I haven't found anything about that directly, but I have seen stuff about using HTML for all or part of the question body, and I know there are facilities for entering math into HTML.

Also, I'm very familiar with using LaTeX to describe equations and other math. I suppose it's too much to hope for to wish that I could enter LaTeX directly into questions and answers here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Relevant: [There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on)

Comment: One might argue that if you need the facilities of LaTeX for your question then your question might be more on-topic in one of the forums like [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/). I won't make that argument myself, there are many times I wished I could use something like LaTeX in one of my SO answers.

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396502/6296561

Answer (score 4):

To enter mathematics on Stack Overflow, we

- [*cannot* use LaTeX via MathJax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282/290085) like they can on [MathOverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/) and [Math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as described in [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/127412).
- *can* use basic Markdown formatting as described on the [Stack Overflow Markdown help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Also, as mentioned by @PresidentJamesK.Polk, we *can* copy-and-paste from [math symbols and operators in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) and [insert images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) into your post.  (Images should be used as a last resort because they cannot easily be edited or searched.)

Comment: There are also various Unicode characters that represent mathematical symbols. And finally, in a pinch, you can put in an image. Images should be a last resort.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using Unicode when possible (and mixed with `<sup>` and `<sub>` you can get pretty far), but sometimes you need something heavier.

1. Go to a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)-enabled site (eg [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/ask)) and write your MathJax in some draft. (Don't post.)
2. Take a screenshot of your equation.
3. Insert picture into page. If you insert the MathJax into your post (maybe as a HTML comment) then you can easily make another screenshot if you need to change something

Note: if you do go the route of using Unicode, you can copy it from your draft's rendered MathJax and paste into your post.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to simply include LaTeX code in your post and then tell readers that the equations can be viewed via a userscript or bookmarklet.

As mentioned [on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/334566), there are currently 42 sites on the network which support the MathJax variety of LaTeX. However, the chatrooms associated with those sites do not support MathJax. In those chatrooms it's common to use the JavaScript bookmarklets created by math.SE mod robjohn to render MathJax. You can read about the bookmarks [on math.meta.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297/207316), or just go straight to the [installation page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/mathjax.html).

These bookmarklets can render MathJax on any Web page, although the output might not be perfect on some pages. I just did a brief test here using a short `\begin{align}...\end{align}` sequence that spans several lines, but unfortunately everything got rendered onto a single line.

---

Another option is [CodeCogs](https://editor.codecogs.com/). For simple equations, you don't have to use their equation editor, you can simply construct a URL by hand by appending the LaTeX code to the CodeCogs prefix. (Of course, the resulting string needs to be a legal URL). You *could* specify GIF or PNG for the image format, but Stack Exchange sites can support SVG, which gives a superior result.

Eg, the URL `https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}` gives this result:

[image: Quadratic formula]

I suppose this is an ok option for single equations, but it's a bit tedious if you need multiple lines.